# Работа с .pkg файлами на Objective-C\Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, mac, package

Здравствуйте, 
Есть ли возможность работать с пакетами Mac OS X (файлы с расширением `.pkg`) при помощи средств языка `Objective-C` / фреймворка `Cocoa`? Например, создавать свои из имеющегося набора данных или же просматривать / считывать содержимое готовых.
Спасибо.

Comment: Способ создания/распаковки пакетов из терминала так же был бы кстати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, отвечу сам.
В пакет разработчика входит всем известный `PackageMaker`. Причем сам его исполняемый файл можно запускать как обычное консольное приложение. А обычные консольные приложения в `Cocoa` лего запускаются при помощи [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Более-менее подробную информацию о работе консольной версии `PackageMaker'a` можно почитать, например, [вот тут](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/packagemaker.1.html).

***Одно примечание:*** вам придется скопировать PM в `bundle` своего приложения (так как, скорее всего у конечного пользователя не будет установлен пакет разработчика). А так как весь `PackageMaker.app` "весит" порядка 4 мб, я бы посоветовал выкинуть из него все ненужное и оставить только необходимые файлы (~1.4мб):

[image]